# How to get the ERWIN diagram in one model into another model

Tags: sql-server, data-modeling, visio, erwin, case-tools

There is a diagram in the first model say model 1 and i need to get the diagram into the 2nd model say  model 2.
Is ther any way to do this in ERWIN?

I have copied the diagram form the first model and tried to paste it on a balnk diagram diagram page in the 2nd model .But this is not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggets that you use complete compare to copy objects from one model to another.